# Uncertainty in orientation of angular momentum

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

[image]

To calculate the uncertainty it looks like I'm going to find an expression for the root mean square of either $J_x$ or $J_y$, or the $J$ in the x/y plane? But I'm not sure if that's what it means by "uncertainty in the orientation". What does that mean?

Comment: In quantum mechanics, the "uncertainty" of an operator $\hat{O}$ usually means its standard deviation $\sqrt{\langle \psi | (\hat{O} - \langle \psi | \hat{O} | \psi \rangle)^2 | \psi \rangle^2 = \sqrt{\langle \psi | \hat{O}^2 | \psi \rangle - \langle \psi | \hat{O} | \psi \rangle^2$.

Comment: Yep, but which Operator should I use to get the uncertainty in the orientation?

Comment: Oh I see what you mean.  I think they mean find $\langle (\hat{J}_x^2 + \hat{J}_y^2) \rangle - (\langle \hat{J}_x \rangle^2 + \langle \hat{J}_y \rangle^2 )$.  I agree the question is not very clearly stated.